# SQLException fail to insert rows into content(...)

Tags: android, sql

Hi i am creating my own content provider,Here is the database creating code:

```
 public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = 
 Uri.parse("content://"+ PROVIDER_NAME + "/user");

 public static final String _ID = "userid";
 public static final String Name = "name";
 public static final String Email_id= "email";
 public static final String Login_id = "login_id";
 public static final String Password = "password";
 public static final String Phonenumber = "phonenumber";
 public static final String Address = "address";

 private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
 "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + 
 " (userid integer primary key autoincrement,name text not null"+
 " email text not null,login_id text not null,password text not null"+
  "phonenumber text not null,address text not null);";
```

And the insert method is below

```
  public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {

      long rowID = userDB.insert(
         DATABASE_TABLE, null, values);


      if (rowID>0)
      {
         Uri _uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_URI, rowID);
         getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(_uri, null);    
         return _uri;                
      }
```

and putting the values using below code

```
 values.put("name",ame);
 values.put("email",Email);
 values.put("login_id",Login);
 values.put("phonenumber",val1);
 values.put("address",Address);
 Uri uri=getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://"+PROVIDER_NAME+"/user"),values);       
      throw new SQLException("Failed to insert row into " + uri);
   }
catch (Exception e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

And i am getting the errors below.

```
Error inserting name=qwe
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native Method)
at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.insert(ContentProvider.java:150)
at com.example.contentprovider.implement.insert(implement.java:128)
Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
android.database.SQLException: Failed to insert row into content://net.learn2develop.provider.user/user
at com.example.contentprovider.implement.insert(implement.java:138)
```

and some more....

help me...

Answer (score 0):

```
SQLiteConstraintException
```

This means you're violating a DB constraint (e.g. Foreing Key). We cannot know which one from the data you've posted.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the contentvalues does not have key value pair for `password` whereas you have explicitly said password should not be null in oncreate. This might be the reason

Comment: i for got to put that line(values.put("password",Password1);) actually, i am entering password also..

Comment: I for got to tell u i put it in compare block ..i.e.  if-else block